# Firebase App Distribution - Multiple IPA for same release/version (per environment) is not working

Tags: ios, circleci, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

I'm using Firebase App Distribution via Circle CI and Fastlane. So far, I am able to submit the build  and validate that the release is available at the Firebase portal, however, even I have differents lanes per environmnet, I can only see just one on the portal. The weird thing is that sometimes the visible build is the one generated by the staging_lane, and others by the production_lane. Does anyone ever face it this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in our case the issue was that both lanes were generating exactly the same IPA, when the lanes were fixed and generate an IPA that was properly set to staging and an IPA thatwas properly set to production, everything works as expected.